# How to find delimiter from string in Console Application

Tags: c#, string

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter a string");
string str = Console.ReadLine();
```

**Note**: User can enter *any* delimiter like `, @ # $ % * &  ; :` etc.

**Example**: For input: `1*2*5*9` the delimiter is `*`

Comment: what about if the input is `1*2#5%9`

Comment: Have you even tried *anything*? We´re not here to do your work. Provide some own idea and ask if you have a specific problem with your solution.

Answer (score 5):

You can try *guessing* with a help of *regular expressions*; let's split the input not by unknown delimiter(s), but by *main text* items (integers?) and we'll get the delimiters as the result:

```
  string source = @"1*2*5*9";

  // Main text pattent; user is supposed to input integers numbers and delimiters
  string bodyPattern = 
    @"-?[0-9]+";

  var delimiters = Regex
    .Split(source, bodyPattern)
    .Select(item => item.Trim())
    .Where(item => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item))
    .Distinct()
    .ToArray();

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, delimiters));
```

Outcome:

```
 *
```

Please, notice that in case of `"1*2#5%9"` input you'll get `["*", "#", "%"]` delimiters.

**Edit:** Do you really want *delimiter(s)*? The much more natural problem is to extract *main text items*. If it's your case, you can solve it with regular expressions as well:

```
 // ["1", "2", "5", "9"]
 var items = Regex
   .Matches(source, bodyPattern)
   .OfType<Match>()
   .Select(match => match.Value) 
   .ToString();
```

Comment: Marvelous answer, could you elaborate a little on the details of the guessing algo?

Answer (score 1):

The following should help

```
char[] delimiter  = {'@','#','&', '*'};    
foreach (char c in str)
{
    if(delimiter.Contains(c)
        //You found your char
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Using system.text.regularexpressions;
  Regex ptr = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") ;
  if(!ptr.Ismatch(str)) //whatever you want
```